# Overhead of Disabling Cell Reuse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, reuseidentifier

So I have 3 sections with 3 rows in each section (9 rows overall), and each row as a `textField`.

I had some problems with the tableView and it was very annoying as the cells gets mixed up with values, when I scroll up and down, and the whole tableView gets messed up. Although it's a lack of logic in my programming that might be causing this, I have decided on an immediate remedy for this problem.

So, I have now **disabled** the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and things seem to be okay now. From the Apple documentation, I can see that reusability can provide good performance for large tableViews. I have now **prevented cell reuse**.

I have just 3 sections with 3 rows each.

1. What exactly is the magnitude of performance drop we are talking here ?
2. How would this affect my whole app, keeping in mind that I have a small tableView in that view ?
3. Are there any complications with regards to the approval of this app in the App-Store ?

p.s. *I am using this approach only for one view. All other views have reusable cells.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for such a small table I don't think it is worth worrying about.

This will have no effect on your app being approved.

It may be best to ask another question with the code causing your issue and then people can help you solve it and you can learn from that, which ultimately will help you much more than sidestepping issues.

Comment: To add to paul's answer, your real problem more than likely has to do with not resetting (setting to nil) your textview for each cell or something similar. But feel free to post a question with your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You won't notice a difference with such a small number of cells.
2. You won't notice a difference with such a small number of cells.
3. No, I really don't think Apple will care whether you reuse cells or not.

Answer (score 0):

The impact is if the cells scroll off the screen you may get UI stuttering as it creates new ones every time, so scrolling would feel less smooth.

Other than that, there would be no other issues.